# Gdalwarp clip with negative buffer

Tags: gdal, buffer, clip, gdalwarp

Is there any simple way to change this command:

`gdalwarp -tr 10 10 -cutline "shape.shp" -crop_to_cutline -of GTiff "S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20200719T161950_20200719T162015_033526_03E28C_C720.SAFE.tif" "S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20200719T161950_20200719T162015_033526_03E28C_C720.SAFE.tif"`

to the one that would clip to cutline, but with negative buffer in meters (if not, at least in pixels?)

Input data is WGS84 UTM zone 34N.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may want to just issue the buffer command in Spatialite SQL. Easiest to do it in two steps:

1. Create buffer, check it's what you want
2. Amend your command to use the new shapefile.

Or you can put the SQL directly in gdalwarp using the `-csql` options. Harder to debug!

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -dialect SQLite \
        -sql \
 "select ST_Buffer(ST_Transform(geometry, 32634), -10) from shp_in" shp_out.shp shp_in.shp
```

(all in one line without the `\`, I'm not sure this will work as typed!)

Comment: as far as I know this is not -10 meters in WGS84, but degrees, am I wrong?

Comment: Ooops, I'm sorry, I forgot about adding the transform. Check the above edits (haven't been able to test). I assumed that your vector data is WGS84 lat/long (e.g.) and you want to convert to UTM34N.